# Webpack reports same name module browser.js when using react-datagrid

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, typescript, webpack, redux

I am trying to use react-datagrid in a Typescript react-redux application. I have installed react-datagrid as recommended, but I am getting strange webpack messages relating to duplicate browser.js modules:

```
WARNING in (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/process/browser.js
There is another module with an equal name when case is ignored.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Rename module if multiple modules are expected or use equal casing if one module is expected.


WARNING in (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/process/browser.js
There is another module with an equal name when case is ignored.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Rename module if multiple modules are expected or use equal casing if one module is expected.

ERROR in /users/simonshapiro/reactexp/src/components/NodeList.tsx
(3,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react-datagrid'.

ERROR in (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/buffer/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'source-map-loader' in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/node-libs-browser/node_modules/buffer
 @ (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/buffer/index.js 1:0-106

ERROR in (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/buffer/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'source-map-loader' in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/node-libs-browser/node_modules/buffer
 @ (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/buffer/index.js 12:14-32

ERROR in (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/buffer/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'source-map-loader' in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/node-libs-browser/node_modules/buffer
 @ (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/buffer/index.js 13:14-32

ERROR in (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/buffer/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'source-map-loader' in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/node-libs-browser/node_modules/buffer
 @ (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/buffer/index.js 11:13-33
```

Here is the Typescript file NodeList.tsx that uses react-datagrid:

```
import * as React from "react";

import DataGrid from 'react-datagrid'

export const NodeList = (props) => (
    <div id="NodeList">
        <h2>{props.heading}</h2>
        <DataGrid idProperty="id" dataSource={props.items}/>
    </div>
    )
```

and the ts.config file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "files": [
        "./typings/main.d.ts",
        "./src/infomodel/InfoModel.ts",
        "./src/components/Hello.tsx",
        "./src/containers/TextContainer.ts",
        "./src/containers/NodeListContainer.ts",
        "./src/index.tsx",
        "./src/reducers/AppLogic.ts"
    ]
}
```

and the webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "./dist/bundle.js",
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'ts-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
        ],

        preLoaders: [
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },

    // When importing a module whose path matches one of the following, just
    // assume a corresponding global variable exists and use that instead.
    // This is important because it allows us to avoid bundling all of our
    // dependencies, which allows browsers to cache those libraries between builds.
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    },
};
```

This has been cross-posted from the react-datagrid Github issues log.

Answer (score 0):

Whenver you install a new dependency in a ts app, you need to run tsd install (or typings install) depending on your project configuration. If that does not work, please post your package.json